# Adobe Stratus, RTMFP, and Cloned Code

Tags: video, adobe, clone, chat, soundcloud-stratus

I want to make a niche ChatRoulette site. I know php/mysql, but I've never worked with Flash.

Is it worth my time to learn Flash/Stratus and code everything myself? (I could buy cloned source code for $99.)

If you do recommend the cloned code route, do you recommend any in particular?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the clones implement rtmfp.
They might be using adobe's rtmfp service but that's only allowed for testing.